# JWT Authentication within a Micro Service architecture

Tags: php, node.js, rest, authentication, microservices

**Question**

Question how is it possible to create an authentication service within a micro-service application and have other services check against that token (JWT) and retrieve a user?

**Possible Solution**

My current thinking is based around the auth service inserting `{ token, user }` into Redis once a user is authenticated. All other service can check against the user's `Authorization: Bearer kdI8$dj$nD&...` header token within Redis.

- If `token` is present in Redis, user is authenticated.
- If `token` is not present in Redis, user is not authenticated.

[image]

1. User sends `{ username, password }` to auth service
2. Auth service authenticates credentials and retrieves `{ token, user }`
3. Auth service inserts `{ token, user }` into Redis
4. User makes request to `Service-1` with `{ token }`
5. `Service-1` loooks for `{ token }` in Redis and retrieves `{ token, user }`
6. `Service-1` does its thing and sends back `{ data }`

Are there any possible security, logic or architectural problems with this approach?

Comment: you don't make it clear where is your user in relation to the services, and where are the services in relation to Redis? In particular, I am wondering how do you know its the same user between checks in redis. (ie isn't the point of the jwt for the user to carry it around with him to prove who he is)

Comment: I have cleared up the diagram and added a some flow-steps :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really clear why you would want to store tokens in Redis. The security token typically contains information about the user (claims data) already. If you need information about the user that is not stored in the token, you should be able to look that up by a simple database query on the user id claim.

Each service can validate the incoming token by checking its [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) (only needs the public key of the signing certificate for this), lifetime (when does the token expire), audience (who is the token for) etc. If the caller presents a valid token, the user is authenticated.

Comment: Although each service then must have authentication logic, IMO very bad practice as code would be replicated or in same cases written again in different languages. So I would REALLY want to avoid that approach?

Comment: Sure, every service will need authentication code. You would typically use a library (via a NuGet package) to validate the token, but if your services are written in different languages that code would indeed be duplicated. I don't see how using a shared cache really improves this.

Comment: because there is only a single auth service that inserts authenticated user + token into the store. That store becomes the authority on authentication, its distributed, clustered and accessible to all other services. At anytime i can change how the auth is executed from within the auth service. The way you are describing your stuck with your initial decision. ?

Comment: I'm not really following you. What is the goal of this design? Is it to reduce the token check to a lookup in Redis? If so, who will check if the token is not expired? The token in the cache does not change once your auth service puts it there.

Comment: The goal is this: one single auth service, no replication and redundant auth code across multiple services that may or may not be written in different languages. Avoiding one of the largest pitfalls in engineering: writing the same code more then once. The auth service would monitor the store (Redis is a key value store, cache just being one of its applications) and expire / renew / authenticate tokens.

Comment: You realize there are standard libraries for token validation in every language? I think one of the biggest pitfalls in software engineering is writing your own security implementation.

Comment: Wow ok thank you so much. You lead me down the right path in the end. Can you please update your answer with the following details that I missed: JWT tokens actually store information (claims) such as user data, tokens can be validated by any service. The service only need the token along with the secret to decode and validate the token. Oh and add antithetical details :) this question is getting allot of traffic

Comment: You're welcome, you can upvote and/or accept the answer to show appreciation. :) I've updated the answer to clarify. Not sure what you mean with the last sentence of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using this approach you will have to validate the token in all your services, if you are okay with this then you are probably fine.

The access token may have an expire time that will make it necessary to use a refresh token to get a new access token from the auth service:

- When the access token expires you would return a 401 to the client, from the Service X that you are trying to talk to.
- The client would have to call the Auth service providing a refresh token, getting a new access token

  - Finaly the client would be hitting the Service X again with this new access token, have it validated and get the expected response from Service X.

In my [recent assignment](http://www.davidkarlsson.no/readPost/Using_PassportJS_to_build_an_authentication_proxy) I wrote a micro-service that proxied all the requests validating their tokens, the proxy handled everything from login/auth to roles and sending 401's for expired tokens and revoking refresh tokens etc. I think this gave me a greater separation of concerns than having to deal with tokens in all services. However it ofcourse makes the proxy a possible bottle neck into the system, autoscaling of the auth service is meant to deal with this in my case.

Also I did not user redis but stored a hashed key (consisting of hashed accesstoken properties + salt) in the accesstoken that I could validate by rehashing the other properties of the accesstoken+salt.

**Important Note:** In the refresh token scenario above my proxy only would experience load for an invalid/expired accesstoken, whilst in your scenario any service could be reached with invalid tokens, I don't know if this is of any concern in your particular case but it is probably worth mentioning...

Another approach would be to let Service-A and Service-B call the auth service to validate the tokens, but this would infer a lot of more traffic between the services since each HTTP request with a token has to be validated. In this scenario as well a invalid token request would reach your Service X and hence infer some load on it...